# react native testing library, No instances found with testID

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, testing, react-native-testing-library

Im getting the error,

No instances found with testID: CreateAccount.errorMessage

But Im referencing the ID on "CreateAccount.js"

```
   <ErrorText
      text={this.state.errorMessage}
      testID="CreateAccount.errorMessage"
    />
```

Then on "CreateAccount.test.js"

```
test("display error msg if all fields are not completed", () => {
  const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(<CreateAccount />);

  fireEvent.press(getByText("Submit"));

  console.log(getByTestId("CreateAccount.errorMessage").props);
});
```

What is missing on my component for the testID to work?

thanks in advance

Comment: What does your `CreateAccount` component looks like?

Comment: I also have same problem, it also error in <Text> component